# How can I efficiently transpose array and assign to an array with a different type

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Consider the following:

```
program main
integer, parameter :: n=10, m=20
integer ints(n,m)
real floats(m,n)

!... initialize ints
! ...

floats=transpose(ints)
!... do stuff with floats

end
```

looking at the documentation for gfortran, it seems that `transpose(ints)` will return an integer array which will then be cast to reals.  In this operation, the compiler (gfortran) creates a temporary array for the transposed array which seems like a waste (compile with `gfortran -O3 -Warray-temporaries -o test test.f90`).  Also note that if you change the `real` array "floats" into an `integer` array, the warning goes away.

Is there a way to do this (for arbitrary types) without generating a temporary array?  (I also tried `floats(:,:)=transpose(ints)` because I read somewhere that it mattered ... ).  Does it behave this way with other compilers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
floats = transpose(real(ints))
```

but I wouldn't be very surprised if gfortran (or any other compiler) generated a temporary array to implement this. I'd be more surprised if it didn't.

You might also try

```
forall (J=1:N, K=1:M) floats(K, J) = real(ints(J, K))
```

Again, I wouldn't be surprised if a compiler created a temporary array to implement this.

Comment: I was hoping you'd answer.  The first still generates a temporary (in gfortran).  The second doesn't (or at least it doesn't warn me about it).  Also, if I remove `real` in `real(ints(j,k))` then it should work for arbitrary types.  (mainly I need all permutations of integer,real and double precision).  It seems silly to me that the compiler would need to generate array temporaries in this situation (I could write a module to do it using subroutines and overloading as necessary), but maybe I'm just naive.

Comment: In place transposition is not trivial.  See, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition

Comment: @M.S.B. I'm not talking about doing it in place -- In fact, I don't want to do it in place. (I don't want `ints` to be changed) -- I do however, have a very good place for the result to go (`floats`).  I suppose part of the difficulty here is that `transpose` could be used as part of a larger expression where a temporary would be necessary...

Answer (score 1):

```
do i = 1, n
do j = 1, m
    floats(j,i) = real(ints(i,j))
enddo
enddo
```

You could make your own `transpose` interface for handling different data types, although it would have to be a subroutine and not a function.

```
interface transpose_
    module procedure transpose_ints_to_reals
end interface

subroutine transpose_ints_to_reals(ints_in, reals_out)
...
end subroutine

call transpose_(ints,floats)
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that I can do this, however, it is error prone as I would have to duplicate the same routine many times for different types.  If Fortran had some mechanism to auto-generate the function for the different types and overload it, that would be perfect, but AFIK, that mechanism doesn't exist.

Comment: Yep, Fortran doesn't have a lot of nice features :(

Comment: Fortran does have a lot of nice features for numerics though.  The existence of a `transpose` function to begin with is very nice.